# VB.net mySQL update all data in ListView

Tags: mysql, vb.net

How can i update all the data that shown in the listview? This code is not working properly it only updates the first row in the listview

```
   con.Open()
        cmd.Connection = con
        cmd.CommandText = "update pawn set status = 'Redeemed' where pawn_id = '" & ListView3.Items.Item(0).SubItems(0).Text & "'"
        dr = cmd.ExecuteReader

        MsgBox("Successfully Added", vbInformation)
        con.Close()
```

Comment: Of course it does, because you are only executing the command for the first item in the list. Iterate through the list, or adjust your SQL query.

Comment: can you please tell me what to do? I've been looking for the answer for hours

Comment: Do you understand how to iterate the list items?  Any answer is going to depend on you knowing how to do that.

Comment: You would have a much easier time interacting with the DB if that was a DataGridView instead.  The columns and rows add themselves